# R classified input opening as panchromatic image in Erdas

Tags: r, unsupervised-learning

I did unsupervised classification on a raster stack with 100 classes and the output seems fine. When I am opening the same output in erdas it is opening as a panchromatic image instead of a thematic one with 255 classes.

what should I do?